# Spring MVC with MongoDB - Sorting and Limits

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, mongodb-java

What's the best way to sort a MongoDB query result in Spring MVC?  I've got all the mappings set up in the XML files and I can call the myrepository.findAll() in the Service class just fine and it's working great.

How can I sort those results (by date for example) and/or limit the results (like by 3, etc).  In Mongo itself it's pretty easy to just do a db.mycollection.find().sort({ postedAt : -1});  Or just throw a .limit(3) to get the first 3 results.

What's the best way to handle this in a Spring MVC environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *myrepository* object is an instance of MongoRepository, you could call the **findAll** method with a Pageable object as parameter.

```
Pageable page = new PageRequest(0, 3, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "postedAt"));
myrepository.findAll(page);
```

Actually, this method is from PagingAndSortingRepository interface.

Answer (score 0):

I feel its good to sort in the MongoDB itself as we have lots of options there, for example the way you mentioned will give the sorted list. You can define an index which can make the sorting easier as well. Displaying in the spring environment then should be a no-brainer. Also if you have the pagination kind of use case then as you told you can limit at the mongo layer and bring that many records to the spring environment.